# How to get google clould talent job list?

Tags: node.js, react-native, google-api, google-cloud-talent-solution

How to get list of job from google talent-solution?

[image]

I have also refer this : https://cloud.google.com/talent-solution/job-search/docs/before-you-begin
https://jobs.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v3

but can't understand, How to get JSON response for job listing.
Please provide proper step for access data like image.

Answer (score -1):

The Node.js SDK looks pretty straight forward. Try it out
https://cloud.google.com/talent-solution/job-search/v2/docs/libraries#client-libraries-resources-nodejs

For getting the list of jobs, you can try this
https://cloud.google.com/talent-solution/job-search/v2/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/list#google.jobs.v2.JobService.ListJobs

Thanks

Comment: Node JS File give error like this: code: 403,
  errors: 
   [ { message: 'The caller does not have permission',
       domain: 'global',
       reason: 'forbidden' } ]

Comment: getting the list of jobs, you can try this https://cloud.google.com/talent-solution/job-search/v2/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/list#google.jobs.v2.JobService.ListJobs {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Project 292824132082 is temporarily blacklisted.. Request ID for tracking: dbd43848-1596-43cd-b4d4-bbe8c0d2408c:APAb7IToTa74ZBgwtZj0qyiaYM51fEvp4A==",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}

Comment: Seems like you need to contact Google support, because it says forbidden. So the API seems to be working, its that you need proper permissions to get through.